# Run a ruby cucumber feature file from command prompt

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, ui-automation, browser-automation

I have a bunch of Ruby cucumber feature files that are running from Ruby mine IDE.
I am trying to run the same from the command prompt which is failing. Please find the run configuration setting of the successful run from the ruby cucumber from Ruby Mine IDE and suggest me a command to run from the command prompt.
[image]
My cucumber.yml contains:
default: --no-source --color --format pretty  --format json_pretty --out results.json --format html --out results.html

Comment: Please share the command you type at your prompt and the error message. This might give us better idea of why it doesn't work for you.

A better channel for help might be the Cucumber slack or the Cucumber mailinglist. More information is available here: https://cucumber.io/support

Comment: This is the command that i have tried running from the command prompt: 
 TEST_SERVER and TEST_BROWSER are environment variables arguments.                                                                               
C:\Users\Spoluri\Ruby-Automation\Secure_Site\features>Bundle exec cucumber -r step_definitions/ Messages/loginpage.feature -t @login TEST_SERVER=staging;TEST_BROWSER=ie

Comment: Error Message:  uninitialized constant LoginPage (NameError)                          where LoginPage is a Class Name                                                                                              @login
Feature: Logging into QA

  Background:                 # Messages/loginpage.feature:4                            
    Given I am a User # step_definitions/loginpage.rb:1
      uninitialized constant LoginPage (NameError)
      ./step_definitions/loginpage.rb:2:in `/^I am a User$/'
      Messages/loginpage.feature:5:in `Given I am a User'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, I required one level up and it worked.
I tried this command it worked:
Bundle exec cucumber features/Messages/loginpage.feature -t @login TEST_SERVER=staging TEST_BROWSER=ie